# How to change JDK set by SBT import in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, sbt-idea

When Scala plugin reimports an SBT project in IntelliJ IDEA, it changes the project's JDK to 1.6. Is it a way to choose which JDK version Scala plugin sets during reimport of the STB project.

Comment: What's the version of IDEA? What about SBT? What about `build.sbt`?What `SDKs` do you have in `Platform Settings` in IDEA? Can you check `Project SDK` in `Project` in `Project Settings` and ensure it's `1.7` or whatever name you gave for 7 or the expected version of JDK.

Comment: on SBT level you can set these JDK options `javacOptions in Compile ++= Seq("-source", "1.7", "-target", "1.7", "-Xlint:unchecked", "-Xlint:deprecation")` in settings. Maybe it will help IntelliJ to figure it out.

Comment: Good to hear that! I'll convert my comment to an answer then ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set JDK options like these `javacOptions in Compile ++= Seq("-source", "1.7", "-target", "1.7", "-Xlint:unchecked", "-Xlint:deprecation")`, etc on SBT level in your project settings. It should help IntelliJ to use correct JDK version.

Comment: after making this change it may not be enough to just refresh from the SBT pane, I add to reimport it altogether

Comment: This didn't work for me. I have those settings in my SBT, but when I re-import in IntelliJ, it resets the project to JDK 1.6 (the first in my list). :-(

Answer (score 1):

Running sbt in the following way resolved it for me

```
sbt -java-home `/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7`
```